# Find scale of axis, given angle between axis in a drawing

Tags: geometry

Lets draw a cube on a 3d coordinate system as follows:

[image]

Notice that even though it's a cube (all of its sides are equal length), side c in the drawing is being scaled down by a factor of two, because the z axis is distorted because of its scewed location towards the other axis.

Lets now scew z to an angle $\beta$ to x, and y to an angle $\alpha$ to x:

[image]

My question:

Given those two angles $\beta$ and $\alpha$, how can you find how y and z are scaled with respect to x? Is there some kind of formula or proof for this?

Comment: Your first drawing is not a possible view of an actual cube in either perspective or orthogonal projection. It can be produced by an oblique projection, but the angle and scale of the "skewed" axis can be anything you like in an oblique projection. I suppose you are looking specifically for orthogonal projections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a beautiful algebraic identity that relates the edges of a 3D cube to their orthogonal projections onto a plane.

If   a cube in space  has one vertex at the origin, and if the three 3-dimensional edge vectors extending from that vertex are denoted in upper-case as  $\vec A$, $\vec B$, $\vec C$, then their projections onto the $(x,y)$ plane  can be denoted in lower-case as $\vec a =(a_1,a_2)$, $\vec b=(b_1, b_2)$ and $\vec c= (c_1, c_2)$.
Actually it is  more convenient to represent these 2D vectors as complex numbers $z_1 = a_1+i a_2$, $z_2 = b_1+i b_2$, and $z_3= c_1+ ic_2$.

*The algebraic identity these complex numbers satisfy is  simply
$z_1^2+ z_2^2 + z_3^2 =0$.*

Thus any two determine the third uniquely, up to a minus sign.

**Conversion of the complex identity into real equations**

In your problem you are given one edge vector along the $x$ axis, which we designate as $\vec c= (1,0)$, hence $z_3 =1$. The other two edge vectors can be written in complex  polar form using Euler notation as $z_1= r_1 e^{i \alpha}$  and $z_2= r_2 e^{i \beta}$ where the known angles in your diagram for the twisted axes are estimated to be $\beta = 120^\circ$ (converted to radians) and similarly  it appears that the known angle $\alpha =70^{\circ}$.

Substituting into the complex quadratic you deduce

$0= r_1^2 e^{2i\alpha} + r_2^2 e^{2i \beta} + 1$

Taking real and imaginary parts of this identity gives

(i) $r_1^2 \sin (2\alpha) + r_2 ^2 \sin (2\beta) =0$
and (ii) $ r_1^2 \cos (2\alpha)+ r_2 ^2 \cos(2\beta) =-1$.

Use (i) to solve for $r_2^2$ in terms of $r_1^2$; then substitute into (ii) to solve for $r_1^2$.

Then take square roots to find the values of $r_1$ and $r_2$.

The numbers $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the numbers you seek. They are the  2D lengths of the projections onto the plane of the edges of the cube.

**Worked numerical example.**

From your picture I estimated that the twisted axes make angles of about 70 and 120 degrees from the $x$ axis.  These were converted to radian measure, then the system of two linear equations for the squared values  $\rho_1= r_1^2, \rho_2= r_2^2$ were solved. Finally their square roots determine $r_1$ and $r_2$. The values obtained are approximately $r_1=.937$ and $r_2=.807$.

[image]

**The force-equilibrium interpretation**

The complex squares $w_1= z_1^2, w_2= z_2^2, w_3= z_3^2$ can be regarded as three force vectors in the plane that are in mutually self-cancelling equilibrium: $w_1+w_2+w_3=0$. This interpretation makes it easy to quickly see that certain configurations of the edge projections are physically impossible.

**Justification** For a derivation of the complex quadratic identity see my discussion in this post: [enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597585/obtaining-the-size-of-a-square-from-an-angled-view/4597884#4597884)

**X-rated comments intended for an advanced audience**.
In the discussion in the link, we treated a slightly different version of the problem, in which one was asked to reconstruct the missing third dimension of each edge vector, given the planar projections of all  three edges. Although this appears to be a quite different physical problem than that in the current post, it turns out that the problems are duals of one another, and both can be solved by the same method.  The same principles are applicable in both discussions because the transpose of an orthogonal matrix is also an orthogonal matrix.