# 2D different integer valued vertices coordinates of cube projection

Tags: geometry, 3d, projective-geometry

On paper we, orthogonal, project a cube as in provided image. But is it always really a cube? And, in this particular example, the 8 different 2D coordinates of the vertices have integer values. But is that even possible? I believe it is not possible (integer valued coordinates for distinct projections), but, is there a, perhaps simple, proof of this general impossibility, or, is there an example of a possibility?

[image]

Comment: It is really a hexagonal parallelogon.

Comment: @peterwhy : the example is visually not very convincing as example of a valid possibility, but how to prove it is **not** possible to have integer valued orthogonal projection coordinates (if so)?

Comment: If you project parallel to an edge of the cube the image is a square and integer coordinates are possible. I suspect it's impossible otherwise. I hope someone posts a solution.

Comment: @EthanBolker : very true ! thanks, but what about 8 different vertex projections, I will adjust question and title

Comment: @EthanBolker I added an example below with 8 different integer 2D coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible with all $8$ vertices having different integer $(x,y)$ coordinates, for example:

$$\require{cancel}
\begin{array}{cccc}
& (-9,20,\cancel{12}) & ----- & (11,20,\cancel{27})\\
(-21,5,\cancel{28}) & ----- & (-1,5,\cancel{43}) & \mid\\
\mid & \vdots & \mid & \mid\\
\mid & \vdots & \mid & \mid\\
\mid & \vdots & \mid & \mid\\
\mid & \vdots & \mid & \mid\\
\mid &(0,0,\cancel0) & \cdots\cdots\mid \cdots\cdots& (20,0,\cancel{15})\\
(-12,-15,\cancel{16}) & ----- & (8,-15,\cancel{31})\\
\end{array}$$

This example is based on the $3-4-5$ right-angled triangle, by rotating a cube twice along two axes by $\tan^{-1}(3/4)$. The cube side length is $25$.

---

To create this type of example, first start with a unit cube with vertices $\mathbf v\in\{0,1\}^3$.

Pick a Pythagorean triple where $a^2+b^2=c^2$, then scale each vertex by $c$ and rotate about the $x$-axis:

$$\mathbf v \mapsto c\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & b/c & -a/c\\
0 & a/c & b/c
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf v
= \begin{pmatrix}
c & 0 & 0\\
0 & b & -a\\
0 & a & b
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf v$$

Then pick another (or the same) Pythagorean triple where $d^2+e^2=f^2$, then scale the above result by $f$ and rotate about the $y$-axis:

$$\begin{align*}
T(\mathbf v)
&= f\begin{pmatrix}
e/f & 0 & -d/f\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
d/f & 0 & e/f
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
c & 0 & 0\\
0 & b & -a\\
0 & a & b
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf v\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
e & 0 & -d\\
0 & f & 0\\
d & 0 & e
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
c & 0 & 0\\
0 & b & -a\\
0 & a & b
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf v\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
ce & -ad & -bd\\
0 & bf & -af\\
cd & ae & be
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf v\\
\end{align*}$$

Lastly, project the above result parallel to the $z$-axis, and only keep the $(x,y)$-coordinates unchanged:

$$\begin{align*}
P(T(\mathbf v))
&= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0&0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}T(\mathbf v)\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
ce & -ad & -bd\\
0 & bf & -af
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf v\\
\end{align*}$$

The example above is from picking $3^2+4^2=5^2$ twice.

---

For your initial projection, by hand calculation, for now I can only fit a $2\sqrt{10}\times 2\sqrt{10}\times 4\sqrt{3}$ cuboid, i.e. a $\sqrt5 :\sqrt 5 :\sqrt 6$ cuboid.

Comment: To prove impossibility of the orignal example I would start with the method outlined here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4667386/find-scale-of-axis-given-angle-between-axis-in-a-drawing/4667756#4667756

Comment: @MathSensei : thanks, and, sure, original example is not possible ... which is why I asked for generalization or possible example. I am sorry if the way I expressed my question was not very clear.

Comment: @peterwhy : just to be sure I understand the visual point of view in the construction, one rotates over x and y so one looks orthogonal direction z, right?

Comment: @FirstNameLastName Right, the projection would be parallel to the $z$-direction, i.e. to drop the $z$-coordinate and only keep $x,y$ unchanged.

Comment: @MathSensei Thanks for the link. There was a deleted answer here that tried to find a cube for the original example, and the answer looks reasonable, but I am not sure why it was deleted by the author...

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but just a compliment to @peterwhy's excellent solution and a visual illustration of that solution: a projection of a cube with side length 25.

fwiw: it 'looks' much more like a cube than my example ...

[image]

Comment: It may look like a cube, "But is it always really a cube?" has to be *false*. Say if I scale my example cube non-uniformly along the $z$-direction alone, then I get a parallelepiped with the same projection.

Comment: @peterwhy : Right, I will adjust text to not harm the spirit of your answer. So correct property of these drawings is if they can or cannot be a projection of a cube. Your example is extra elegant in that the projection is along one of the cube's directions but such was not even required.

Comment: fwiw: I spotted a somewhat loosely related result: sum of the squares of the lengths of the orthogonal projections of the edges of a cube with edge length a to a plane equals 8a^2.