what is the maximum number of vertices after a 3D planar and regular polygon was truncated by a 3D box?
Let me use a 3D square as an example first. A 3D planar square has four vertices. If this square was truncated by a 3D box, then I can tell that the maximum number of vertices ($NV_{max}$) is eight, as shown by the pictures below.
Before truncation:

After truncation:

I can draw this conclusion because I can count all possible results. If the square was thoroughly inside the box, then the number of newly-generated vertices is four (i.e., no truncation actrually happens). If the square was a little bit larger than the box (as shown in the picture above), then the number of vertices after truncation is eight.
However, for a regular pentagon (with five vertices), or a regular hexagon (with six vertices), or a regular heptagon (with seven vertices), or other regular polygons with more vertices, how can one predict the $NV_{max}$ value after truncation? Such a polygon has arbitary orientations and sizes. It seems that counting all possible results for regular polygons with more vertices is difficult. Is there a relationship between $NV_{max}$ and the number of vertices ($NV$) before truncation?

The linear forms in 3 space variables whose  pairs of level sets carve out the pairs of antipodal faces of the box each restricts to the plane of the polygon to become a linear form on that plane. The three families of level sets drawn on that planar polygon are characterized by 2D gradient vectors drawn on that plane.  Perhaps this reduction to a 2D diagram might clarify matters.?

The orthogonal projection of a triad of orthonormal 3D gradient  vectors onto a plane produces a triplet of planar vectors that must satisfy an algebraic relation which can be encoded as $z_1^2 + z_2^2 + z_3^2=0$ when the planar vectors are identified with complex numbers. That might be relevant to your problem.

Mre details: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597585/obtaining-the-size-of-a-square-from-an-angled-view/4597884#4597884

@MathFont Yes. Projecting the problem to 2D spaces would be helpful. So, the question becomes: if a 2D arbitaty regular polygon (with the number of vertices denoting as $NV$) was truncated by a 2D square, then what is the maximum number of vertices ($NV_{max}$)? Maybe $NV_{max} = NV +4$?

Are both the planar polygon and the 3D polygon convex ? If not, it is "number of vertices (=number of lines) of the planar" $*$ "number of faces/planes of the enclosing 3D shape".

I might be missing something, but since you've said this polygon is regular (so in particular, convex), each face of the box can be intersected by at most two of the edges of the polygon. So the maximum number of vertices you can possibly achieve is $12$ (and you can achieve this with a hexagon).

As Chris Lewis says in a comment, if a polygon is convex, any face of the box can intersect at most two edges of the polygon. The plane of the polygon will intersect the face in a line segment. Every intersection of the polygon with the face will lie on that segment. If there are more than two such intersections, all but two will lie between other points of intersection on that segment. But by the convexity of the polygon, that puts these additional intersection points in the interior of the polygon, not on its edges.
If a polygon edge intersects the same face in more then one point, then the entire edge lies in the plane of the face and is thus not truncated by this face. (If it passes though a border of the face, then it is truncated instead by the other face forming that border.) So we only need to worry about edges intersecting faces in a single point.
Since the box itself is convex, if an edge of the polygon intersects a face in a point, on one side of the face, the edge extends inside, while on the other side it extends outside the box. In the outside direction, the edge cannot intersect the box again, as boxes are convex. Thus the vertex on that side will be outside, and thus truncated. So every intersection of polygon edge and box face will result in at least one original polygon vertex being removed. Any polygon vertex is the endpoint of at most two intersected edges, so if there $k$ points of intersection, then at minimum of $\frac k2$ of the original vertices are removed by the truncation.
The box has six faces, each of which can intersect at most two edges, adding $12$ vertices in total. But at least $\frac{12}2 = 6$ of the original vertices are lost in the process, so the total increase in vertices can be no more than $6$. If the original polygon had $n$ vertices, the truncated polygon can have no more than $n+6$. For $n\ge 6$, it is not too hard to find examples where $6$ new vertices are added. So $n+6$ is the maximum, not just an upper bound.
For $n = 3,4,5$, each edge of the polygon can intersect the box in at most two points, picking up $2n$ new vertices. But then all the original vertices will be lost, so when $n < 6$, the maximum number of vertices on the truncated polygon is $2n$.

Yes. The polygon is planar, regular, and convex, with arbitary size and orientation. But in what situation, a polygon can intersect moer than four faces of the box?

@TingchangYin - Start with a horizontal plane bisecting the box. Now raise the plane at one corner of the rectangle, and lower it at the opposing corner. When you tilt it far enough, it will rise past the vertex at that corner, and drop below the vertex at the opposing corner. At this point it intersects all six sides of the box. Drawing a convex polygon on the plane intersecting all six sides is clearly possible. A regular polygon may prove to be more of an issue. My post is about arbitrary convex polygons. But I suspect it can also be done for $n \ge 6$.
